# How to get range of cells which have same data with the active cell in the same column please? GG App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an active cell with data and I want to select the range of all cells that have same data with the active cell. I just need the range with the same column as the active cell please
GG App Script

Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findMatchingRangesinSameColumn(rgA1= "B2") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange(rgA1);
  const t = rg.getValue();
  const rows = sh.getRange(1,rg.getColumn(),sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().map((e,i) => (e == t) ? i + 1:"").filter(e => e).join(",");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rows));

}
```